TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString') in NextJS
I'm doing an app using NextJS and NextUI. I wanna add Chart from ApexCharts.js. I did it and works nice but nextjs raise an error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString').
I'm importing chart with dynamic so I set ssr false:
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
const Chart = dynamic(() => import('react-apexcharts'), { ssr: false });

But, when I import like: import Chart from 'react-apexcharts'; works nice but raise the error: GET http://localhost:3000/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
There's an solution for this bug? I couldn't fix it.
<Chart
    options={monthlyOptions}
    series={monthlySeries}
    type="area"
    height={"350"}
/>


I just added width={"100%"} in the charts and works!
